# BufferedWriter.write() method doesn't write integers to file

Tags: java, file

```
public void saveToTextFile(String outText) throws IOException
   {

       BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outText));
       String[] keys=new String[words.size()];
       int[] values=new int[words.size()];
       int i=0;

       for(String word : words.keySet())
       {
          keys[i]=word;
          values[i]=words.get(word);
          i++;
          if(i==words.size()) //Έχουμε διασχίσει όλο το HashMap
          {
              break;
          }
       }

       bubbleSort(values,keys);

       for(i=0;i<words.size();i++)
       {
           out.write(keys[i]);
           out.write(",");
           out.write(values[i]);
           out.write("\n");
       }

       out.close();
   }
```

I have the above function and when I open the file it creates it's like: 
hello, you, are, fine, how, thanks, too, world, and some weird symbols after the first two commas. It's like out.write(values[i]); and out.write("\n"); aren't working! I checked the arrays after the bubbleSort* and they are just fine! The problem appers to be in writing the file...

This is what I get, whick is right:

```
Word: hello Frequency: 2
Word: you Frequency: 2
Word: are Frequency: 1
Word: fine Frequency: 1
Word: how Frequency: 1
Word: thanks Frequency: 1
Word: too Frequency: 1
Word: world Frequency: 1
```

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's executing exactly [as documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29)

> Writes a single character.
>
> **Parameters:**
> `c` - int specifying a character to be written

I suspect you want:

```
out.write(String.valueOf(values[i]));
```

This overrides `Writer.write(int)`, which is [slightly more clearly documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write%28int%29):

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

Comment: I work on netbeans and if I type out.write it shows a list of possible parametres. int i is among them. However, I don't know why if it doesn't work! 

Thank you very much!!!! It worked of course! :)

Comment: @user2202007: I explained why it didn't work. The method is there, it just doesn't do what you want it to. You should *always* read the documentation for a method if it doesn't behave as you expect, or preferably read the docs before you use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to write String**. Try either of the below

- out.write("123");
- out.write(new Integer(123).toString());
- out.write(String.valueOf(123));

In above example, assuming 123 is written to file.